# Как установить свои размеры табов

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qss, qtabbar

Как сделать кнопки табов больше по размеру?

Пример на изображении (табы Компоненты и Смеси)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас получаются обычные стандартные табы.

Код ниже:

**UI_app2.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
    self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
    self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
    self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(600, 420)
    self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

    self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab1.setObjectName("tab1")
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "tab1")

    self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab2.setObjectName("tab2")
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2, "tab2")

    self.grid_main = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
    self.grid_main.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
    Form.setLayout(self.grid_main)
```

**app2.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from UI_app2 import Ui_Form
import sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять импорты под *PySide2* и установите размеры и цвета какие вам нравятся.

```
import sys
'''
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from UI_app2 import Ui_Form
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from UI_app2 import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(600, 420)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab1.setObjectName("tab1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "tab1")

        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2.setObjectName("tab2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2, "tab2")

        self.grid_main = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.grid_main.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        Form.setLayout(self.grid_main)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        
stylesheet = """
    QTabBar {
        background: magenta;
    }
    QTabBar::tab {
        background: rgb(34, 137, 163);
        color: white;
        height: 60px;
        width: 300px;            
        font-family: Ubuntu;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    QTabBar::tab:selected {
        background-color: rgb(48, 199, 184);
        color: #000000;
    }
    QTabWidget {
        background: white;
    }
    QTabWidget::pane {
        background: white;
        border: none;
    }
"""
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)                        # +++
    
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]